# neo4j RuntimeError: No session defined

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

```
class Client
=begin
  Clients are individual users
=end
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  include Neo4j::UndeclaredProperties
  include Neo4j::Timestamps # will give model created_at and updated_at timestamps 

  property :bot_client_id
  property :sms
  property :telegram_id
  property :first_name
  property :last_name
  property :email

end
```

When I create a new node, there is no uuid populated:

```
client = Client.new
```

when I try to find a created client, I get a runtime error:

```
client = Client.find_by(bot_client_id: 'botid')
```

Details of the error:

```
RuntimeError: No session defined!
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/neo4j-8.0.13/lib/neo4j/active_base.rb:9:in `block in current_session'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/neo4j-8.0.13/lib/neo4j/active_base.rb:8:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/neo4j-8.0.13/lib/neo4j/active_base.rb:8:in `current_session'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/neo4j-8.0.13/lib/neo4j/model_schema.rb:35:in `model_constraints'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/neo4j-8.0.13/lib/neo4j/model_schema.rb:131:in `each_schema_element'
```

I have a `def initialize` method which includes:

```
neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::HTTP.new('http://user:pass@host:7474')
Neo4j::ActiveBase.on_establish_session { Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for establishing the session is right, though I don't know what you mean that it's in a `def initialize`.  Is that in the `initialize` method of a class?  If so, is that class being initialized (maybe put a `puts` in there to see)?  I would suggest putting the setup code instead in some part of your app where everything is being set up globally.

I think I answered the question of the `uuid` not being populated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535208/neo4j-uuid-is-not-created/43541628#43541628) and of course you won't be able to `find_by` until the object is persisted (either through `create` or `save`).

Comment: Thanks. This is not a rails app so don't use a config file.

Comment: I saw this so I need to use this in addition or instead of the code above?  # In JRuby or MRI, using Neo4j Server mode. When the railtie is included, this happens automatically. Neo4j::Session.open(:http) and is the :http a symbol as is or should be the grapheneFB URL with credentials?

Comment: I used `save` and got the following:

client.save
Neo4j::DeprecatedSchemaDefinitionError:           Some schema elements were defined by the model (which is no longer supported), but they do not exist in the database.  Run the following to create them:

rake neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Client,uuid]


And then run `rake neo4j:migrate`

Comment: You should run the `rake` task that is specified to create the migration to create a constraint and then run `rake neo4j:migrate`

Comment: You might also check out the readthedocs site, particularly this section: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/UpgradeGuide.html#indexes-and-constraints