# neo4j uuid is not created

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb, graphenedb

```
class Client
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end

> client = Client.new
 => #<Client uuid: nil, bot_client_id: nil, created_at: nil, email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, sms: nil, telegram_id: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

My expectation is that the uuid would be populated.

Answer (score 1):

The `uuid` is only populated once the node object has been saved.  So you could either do:

```
client = Client.create
```

Or:

```
client = Client.new
client.save
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I need to check now if I am actually establishing a session. I assume I am still not. Thanks.